# How can I send data (NSString) associated to a title with Objective-C?

Tags: java, objective-c

**How can I send data (NSString) associated to a title with Objective-C?**

I have searched, but no one send his data with a title...

I programmed this code in **Java**, and it works fine:

```
httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
    // Allows to send the JSON file.
    .addTextBody("processJson", processJson)
    // Allows to send the picture.
    .addBinaryBody("image", file, ContentType.create("application/octet-stream"), file.getName())
    .build();

// Open connection
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(addressTreat);
request.setHeader("User-Agent", _USER_AGENT);
request.setHeader("Authorization", _basicAuth);
request.setEntity(entity);

// Get the response
responseT = httpClient.execute(request, responseHandler);

// Get the processId
processId = new JSONObject(responseT).getInt("processId");
System.out.println("Treatment OK - Time : " + i/10 +","+i%10 + "s ------- " + responseT);
```

This code returns this:

```
Treatment OK - Time : 0,7s ------- {"access":true,"processId":6135,"status":"todo"}
```

If I delete the line

```
".addTextBody("processJson", processJson)",
```

**or** if I modify the text "processJson" like this:

```
".addTextBody("likeThis", processJson)",
```

I will have this:

```
{"access":true,"error":"variable 'processJson' not set"}
```

with an error.

In Java, I can send the JSON file with a title, named processJson.
It has to be exactly "processJson", or it will not work.

I want the same thing in **Objective-C**. I already have this:

```
picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"facture.jpg"];
NSParameterAssert(picture);
NSString *tmp = [myUrl stringByAppendingString:@"process/"];
NSString *urlTreat = [tmp stringByAppendingString:token];
NSURL * nUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlTreat];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:nUrl ];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[request setValue:@"Mozilla/5.0" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
[request setHTTPBody:processJsonToSend]; // I don't know where to put my title...

NSError *error = nil;
NSHTTPURLResponse *responseCode = nil;
NSData *oResponseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&responseCode error:&error];

NSString* responseT = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:oResponseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Treatment OK - %@", responseT);
```

With that, I have this:

```
Treat OK - {"access":true,"error":"variable 'processJson' not set"}
```

#### After having a good result with the JSON file

I want send an image (picture "name.jpg" or .png) in the same request.

For this problem, I think I can do this (but I can try only if JSON file works so):

```
[request setHTTPBody:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(picture, 0.5)];
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to fix it:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"Mozilla/5.0" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];

NSData *data = [@"facture.jpg" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[manager POST:urlTreat parameters:processJson constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:data name:@"facture.jpg" fileName:@"facture.jpg" mimeType:@".jpg"];
} success:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
    processId = [responseObject valueForKey:@"processId"];
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Apple-provided `NSURLSession` doesn't have support for multipart requests, you need to either build yourself or use a third party library. AFNetworking is pretty popular for Objective C.